# how to combine multiple LINQ Expressions

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How can I combine following LINQ statments into just one statement

```
var albums = db.Albums.Include(a => a.Artist).Include(a => a.Genre);
                var albumByGenre = from a in albums
                                   where a.GenreId == GenreId
                                   orderby a.AlbumId descending
                                   select a;

                List<Album> albumList =  albumByGenre.ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is combined wersion with function syntax

```
var albumList = db.Albums.Include(a => a.Artist).Include(a => a.Genre) //1st part
    .Where(a=>a.GenreId==GenreId).OrderByDescending(x=>x.AlbumId) //2nd part
    .ToList(); //3rd part
```

You can just chain queries into one big query